# Reaload multiple DIVs in various times

Tags: javascript

I have a PHP+HTML+CSS app, this app has the main dashboard with multiple rows and columns in it (called widgets).

**Widget is DIV and have set unique ID and some CSS classes. Like:**

```
<div class="col-2 colstav" id="5">Test 5 velikost 2</div>
<div class="col-6 colstav" id="32">Test 32 velikost 6</div>
<div class="col-4 colstav" id="7">Test 7 velikost 4</div>
```

In PHP variable i have stored time (in miliseconds) for every ID after i need to reload file (content) of the DIV.

**In PHP i have:**

```
$column[5]["file"] = widget5.php;
$column[5]["refresh"] = 4000;
$column[32]["file"] = widget32.php;
$column[32]["refresh"] = 2000;
$column[7]["file"] = widget7.php;
$column[7]["refresh"] = 1000;
```

**I cant find Javascript function for reloading DIVs content in time by PHP variables.**

I found this ( http://jsfiddle.net/YVB9F/ ), but I'm failing to update this JS code :(.

**Specification / Edit**:
I need JS code like this:

```
<script>
var time_div_5 = 4000;
var time_div_32 = 2000;
var time_div_7 = 1000; 

function content(content_file,div_id){
load(content_file) to target(div_id)
}

every(time_div_5){do: content("wg/widget5.php","5")}
every(time_div_32){do: content("wg/widget32.php","32")}
every(time_div_7){do: content("wg/widget7.php","7")}
</script>
```

I know how to add variables from PHP to script.

**After some research ai have this script, but is not working:**

```
<script>
function reload_div(file,iddiv){
$(iddiv).load(file);
}

setInterval(reload_div("widgets/widget1.php",1), 1000);
setInterval(reload_div("widgets/widget2.php",2), 4000);
</script>

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is the content? You're probably going to use `innerHTML`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i will edit and more specify what i need.

Comment: You would first have to load your page with the php variables outputted as JS variables. For ex: `var time_div_5 = <?php echo $column[5]["refresh"]; ?>;`. Basically do this for all your php variables for your JS.

Comment: I believe you should handle the timing on the JS side and make asynchronous GET requests using AJAX or Fetch so that the server can process the new PHP content and the client can request and update it rather than trying some kind of bizarre coordination of timing events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will solve this by generating this code for every widget:

```
<script>setInterval(function() {$('#1').load('widgets/_blank.php');},5000)</script>
```

In PHP:

```
echo "<script>";
echo 'setInterval(function() {'."$('#".$tmp_idwidget."').load('".$temp_path."');},".$tmp_refresh.")";
echo "</script>";
```

And its works, but i think, not most effective and clean way :D.

Answer (score 1):

As [denmch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2953245/denmch) mentioned in the comments you should make asynchronous request using AJAX. The way you are trying to achieve is not a good practice.

Also, I can see you are trying to load content from a file by `jQuery.load()` but your id selector seems wrong, `reload_div("widgets/widget1.php",1)` will try to find the elements matching selector `$(1)` and probably fail. Append `#` character to your `iddiv` parameter inside your `reload_div` function.